# "error: variable might not have been initiailzed"

Tags: java

Doing some Java practice at home and I keep getting an error with this code.
I want to make a program which tells the season of a month that has been entered (in numerical form) but if the number is greater than 12, it should tell us that the month entered is invalid.

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

   class SeasonInput {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a month (in numbered form)");

    String monthentered = input.nextLine();

    int month = Integer.valueOf(monthentered);



    String season;

    if(month <13)   {

    if(month == 12 || month == 1 || month == 2)
        season = "Winter";

    else if(month == 3 || month == 4 || month == 5)
        season = "Spring"; 

    else if(month == 6 || month == 7 || month == 8)
        season = "Summer"; 

    else if(month == 9 || month == 10 || month == 11)
        season = "Autumn"; 
    System.out.println("The season that occurs during that month is " + season);                                    
                        }

    else

    System.out.println("Enter a valid month");
   }    
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a valid error, in your last else you don't set `String season`.

```
String season = null; // <-- give it a null. the error will go away.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have cases where you don't initialize `season`.

This is what the compiler is complaining about.